# How do I index a two-dimensional portion of a two-dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a two-dimensional array that I'm trying to slice down to a certain range in both the columns and the rows. Up until now, I've been using `numpy.where()` to index my array where one index is an array and one is a scalar; i.e., I've been indexing a portion of a single row or column. Now, I would like to get all the entries in a certain range of columns and a certain range of rows, but numpy doesn't seem to like it when I do that.

I've tried this:

```
findex = np.where((freqs>63)&(freqs<92))
findex = np.array(findex[0])
tindex = np.where((t>0.5)&(t<1.5))
tindex = np.array(tindex[0])

print(Xsum[findex,tindex])
```

where Xsum (a spectrogram) is my array and freqs, t are arrays (shape (x,1)) whose shapes match up to the number of columns and rows of Xsum. I need to be able to find entries in Xsum by the values in freqs and t, which is why I've been using `numpy.where()`.

This is the error message I get:

```
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (28,) (15,)
```

I've looked for other ways to do this but no dice. Is there a way for me to index my array so that I get a block of it, not a column or a row?

Edit: 
For example, say my array is:

```
np.array([1,2,3,4],
         [5,6,7,8],
         [9,10,11,12])
```

I want some way to index it to obtain this array:

```
([6,7,8],
 [10,11,12])
```

i.e. the entries in the 2nd-3rd rows and 2nd-4th columns, keeping in mind that I don't know the exact indexes I'm looking for, just the values in the other arrays, which is why I've had to use `numpy.where()`.

Comment: It would help to see a sample of your input and desired output

Comment: @G.Anderson I've added some edits, I hope they're helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Basic indexing with slices is the easiest way:

```
In [382]: arr = np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4)                                                   
In [383]: arr[1:, 1:]                                                                          
Out[383]: 
array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

With lists, or arrays they have to `broadcast` against each other:

```
In [385]: arr[[[1],[2]], [1,2,3] ]                                                             
Out[385]: 
array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Or equivalently with arrays:

```
In [386]: np.ix_([1,2],[1,2,3])                                                                
Out[386]: 
(array([[1],
        [2]]), array([[1, 2, 3]]))
In [387]: arr[_]                                                                               
Out[387]: 
array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

That is a (2,1) array combines with a (3,) (or (1,3)) to select a (2,3) block.

If the two arrays/lists don't match in length, you get error:

```
In [388]: arr[[1,2], [1,2,3] ]                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-388-f14b94e53ccb> in <module>
----> 1 arr[[1,2], [1,2,3] ]

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)
```

If they do match in length, you get a 'diagonal' as opposed to a block:

```
In [389]: arr[[1,2], [1,2] ]                                                                   
Out[389]: array([ 6, 11])
```

The more you understand `broadcasting` the clearer this becomes.  The same rules for adding arrays apply here.

Comment: I understand that the arrays cannot be broadcast together if they are of different shapes; however, in some situations I would want to slice a part of an array that is not a block (for example, the intersection of two rows and three columns). Is this possible, and how could I do this?